# Understanding HttpContext.Current.Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext.cache

I've been making some changes to a site and have noticed that when I make a change in the database, ie. add a new person value, the person's name doesn't appear in a dropdown list.

If I reset the application pool a few times the name does finally appear for me. Though doesn't always seem to for others.

It does seem to be controlled heavily by cache and I've found the following:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("PersohnList", d, Nothing, 
       DateTime.MaxValue, New System.TimeSpan(0, 30, 0), 
       Caching.CacheItemPriority.High, Nothing)
```

I've noticed a few values here of interest,

```
a)  DateTime.MaxValue  
b)  New System.TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)
```

Will the cache expire after 30 mins and insert the new person's name or will it not expire because of DateTime.MaxValue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you explicitly caching the list? I don't think it's cached by default. How is it originally initialized? If it gets populated in, let says Page_Load, then on every refresh/new session it will make a database call. If you're saving it somewhere on the server side, that's a whole different issue.

Comment: Did you read the MSDN page for [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77(v=vs.110).aspx)? Also the fact that it survives more than one reset of the application pool it sounds like your problem is caching on the client side not the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain which would win out. It seems that this code is setting the slidingExpiration and the absoluteExpiration. I would assume the latter would win in this but the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77(v=vs.110).aspx) says that you should only use one or the other. If using the slidingExpiration, you should set the absoluteExpiration parameter to [NoAbsoluteExpiration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.noabsoluteexpiration(v=vs.110).aspx) and if using the absoluteExpiration, you should set the slidingExpiration to [NoSlidingExpiration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.noslidingexpiration(v=vs.110).aspx).

If I were you, I would just invalidate the cache when the value is being updated `(HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("PersohnList")` and reset it again.

Comment: Tbh..not sure which would win out. I'll accept your answer as I'm not sure both need to be set..according to MSDN anyway. Decided to rework how the cached list is working anyway. Resetting the app pool though and clearing cache on browser do work. I think I noticed a bug in how this is put together which would explain why the prob I was having.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for sliding window. Each time another user is touching that key, "PersohnList", the cache expiration adds 30 more minutes. Also, check out System.Runtime.Caching as a more modern alternative.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

"The System.Runtime.Caching namespace contains types that let you implement caching in NET Framework applications.

The classes in this namespace provide a way to use caching facilities like those in ASP.NET, but without a dependency on the System.Web assembly."